# How to get json object using key in typescript?

Tags: json, typescript

I am newbie in typescript so not really good in syntax.

My requirement is I want to get some specific elment from json file in typescript.

Following is piece of code that I am trying here.

Json file

```
{
"Description": "data",
"data_list": {
  "example1": {
    "description": "example1",
    "anothermap":{
       "a": "1",
       "b": "2"
    }
 },
 "example2": {
    "description": "example2"
 }
}
```

}

Typescript file

```
import * as test from '../test.json';

export class Demo extends cdk.Stage {

  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, name: string) {
    super(scope, id);

    #const tskData = test.data_list['example1'];
    const tskData = test.data_list[name];
}
```

in the above example when I try to call json value using literals then it works but not with varible. I can't use any literal here becuase what system needed will come as input.

Following is the error that I am getting it

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '
```

Any help on this would be appriciated

Comment: Error when trying to acccess another map :
Property 'anothermap' does not exist on type '{ description: string;

Answer (score 1):

Typescript determines the json's type from it's structure.

You're trying to index `test.data_list` with any string, but not all strings in the world are present as keys in the json. Try changing name's type to `name: "example1" | "example2"`

Or you can automatically create type for possible name values with `type NameType = keyof typeof test.data_list;` and then simply write `name: NameType`.

Comment: I think this second approach works for me and able to access json data as varible. But my example wasn't simple as I paste here so edit it again.

Comment: json has been edit and now facing another issue while access another map inside the element.
Can you help me on this ?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I could help because I faced a similar issue, but I will leave this to someone more qualified.